# How to read Adb Dumpsys alarm output

Tags: android, cmd, adb, alarmmanager, dumpsys

I'm setting multiple alarms on repeat through alarm manager, they are working fine on the day they got set but not repeating at all. I have updated my code but I can't wait all day to check if the code is even working or not so I have tried adb shell dumpsys alarm command but I don't know how to read the output properly and how to extract the times of alarms being set. I have followed some links to understand the output but none is specifiying how to check the exact time of the alarm being set.
here is my output
[image]

my main code where i'm setting the alarm

```
 final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

   //  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,AllTime[i],AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        //        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,AllTime[i],AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

and this this the broadcast receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
    Log.i("okk", "cathing intent values through break" + Arrays.toString(myStrings));


    createNotification(context, "Time is here baby", "this is the notification text", "Alert");
    Log.i("okk", "cathing intent values through break" + Arrays.toString(myStrings));


}

public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {
    final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();  // unique request code

    // will open mainActivity on notification click, can change it
 //   PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, _id, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);  // changed from 0 to _id

    PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, new Intent(context,MainActivity.class),0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_play)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setContentText(msgText);

    // now intent we want to fire when noti is clicked

    mbuilder.setContentIntent(notificationIntent);

    // how person is notified

    mbuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    mbuilder.setAutoCancel(true); // noti dismisble when user swipe it away

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService((Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));

    //    Log.i("okk", "NOTIFIED " + intent.getExtras());

    notificationManager.notify(1, mbuilder.build());  // changes from 1 to _id
       }
```

Comment: post your code to know how you are setting the alarm

Comment: @OBX just did. check

Answer (score 1):

maybe it can help you, I've created an opensource project with a GUI version of the "adb shell dumpsys alarms" command. You can find it here:

https://github.com/Dottorhouse/DumpsysAlarm

Hopefully it will help you figure out what's wrong